# How dose base pointer address in derived class?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, memory

As I know that we could use base class pointer to address and call virtual functions in derived classes, because base class pointer has a more limited pointer scope. But I just want to know, how does base class pointer know where to start in derived class?

For example, for the record A, B and C all HAS there own data members, we can discuss this issue in two different categories 1. A, B & C all have their virtual functions; 2. A, B & C only have their own data members without any virtual functions

```cpp
class A {...};
class B {...};
class C : public A, public B {...};

C c;
B* b = &c
```

Inside C, A should be placed over the top of B, so how does pointer b know where to start addressing in C?

Comment: Because the compiler knows the size of A. If you output the two pointers you'll see that the value of the pointer has changed. Try `cout << (void*)&c << ' ' << (void*)b << '\n';`

Comment: @john The address won't change. They should print the same thing. Edit: Oh, if they have virtual methods you mean? Yes, then they will be different.

Comment: It doesn't.The base class definition specifies what virtual functions it has. When the pointed-to object is an instance of a derived class, the implementation (aka compiler) ensures that all virtual function calls resolve to overrides of the most derived class. Practically, implementations typically use virtual function tables (vtables) that contain - in some form - pointers to all virtual functions. When constructing an instance of a derived class, the base's vtable is populated with entries for the derived class (since construction of the "derived" part happens after the "base" part)

Comment: @TedLyngmo  At least one of `static_cast<A*>(&c)` and `static_cast<B*>(&c)` must be different from `&c`, since the `A` and `B` subobjects must have different addresses.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, if they have virtual methods. If they haven't, they will both have the same address.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, even without virtual functions they [will print](https://godbolt.org/z/gG8Fr4) different addresses unless `A` and `B` are empty.

Comment: @Evg yes they need variables. Just adding methods wont change the address unless they are virtual

Comment: I was assuming that A and B had member variables.

Comment: @Evg check out update

Comment: @Edee So has your question been answered? When making a pointer to B inside C, the compiler shifts the pointer by the sizeof(A) bytes, so the pointer is pointing to the start of the B object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler knows the layout, so it will emit code, which will calculate the address of the `B` subobject in `C`.

Let's see a simple actual example:

```
class A { int x; };
class B { int y; };
class C: public A, public B { };

B *get(C &c) {
    return &c;
}
```

In `get`, the compiler must calculate where `B` resides in `C`. Here's an example of the compiled code ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/BgKZov)):

```
get(C&):                              # @get(C&)
        lea     rax, [rdi + 4]
        ret
```

This means that the compiler will add 4 bytes to the address of the input argument (`c`), and returns that (it adds 4, because `sizeof(A)` is 4, and the compiler decided to not add any additional padding).

Note, that if `A` is empty, then it is likely that the address of `B` is the same as `C`. And if `A` is not empty (has non-static data members, or has virtual functions), then `B`'s address will likely differ. But all these are implementation details, depends on the platforms ABI (Application Binary Interface).

Comment: Is the last paragraph somehow affected by [EBO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo)?

Comment: @Evg: yes, if the compiler puts `A` first (and `A` is empty), then EBO is needed to have `B` and `C` at the same address.